# De la belle ouvrage

Tags: expressions, genre, origine-ou-raison

[Ouvrage est un nom masculin](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ouvrage/56978), pourtant il existe la locution *[de la belle ouvrage](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ouvrage/56979/locution?q=belle%20ouvrage#157986)* (avec un accord au féminin).

Quelle est l'origine de cette étrangeté?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Une excellente explication](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2073062) sur cette question:

> Le TLFi cite deux remarques à ce sujet :
>
> > Jullien (Lang. vicieux corr., 1853) note: « Ce mot, qui était quelquefois du féminin du temps de Louis XIV, surtout en parlant des ouvrages des femmes, est toujours du masculin aujourd'hui. Ne dites donc pas une belle ouvrage, mais un bel ouvrage » et Dupré 1972 constate: « Dans le langage populaire ou plaisamment, on le met au féminin ».
>
> Et voici la remarque de Littré :
>
> > C'est une faute commise quelquefois dans le peuple, de faire ouvrage féminin. Vaugelas remarque que les femmes, en parlant de leur ouvrage, le faisaient toujours féminin : voilà une belle ouvrage. Il est resté féminin dans le patois normand, comme plusieurs substantifs en age.

Answer (score 5):

Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ouvrage/0) note une remarque faite en 1853 par Bernard Julien dans son ouvrage *Langage vicieux corrigé* au sujet de « ouvrage ». Il écrit que le mot était parfois employé au féminin dans la deuxième moitié du XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, particulièrement lorsque l'on parlait du travail des femmes, mais que le mot est toujours masculin aujourd'hui. Il recommande l'utilisation de « un bel ouvrage » à « une belle ouvrage ».

> Ce mot, qui était quelquefois du féminin du temps de Louis XIV, surtout en parlant des ouvrages des femmes, est toujours du masculin aujourd'hui. Ne dites donc pas une belle ouvrage, mais un bel ouvrage.

Bon nombre d'ouvrages de référence, comme le Larousse cité en question, notent qu'« ouvrage » est souvent familièrement utilisé au féminin en parlant d'un travail soigné (TLF, Petit Robet et Multidictionnaire de la langue française), mais n'en expliquent pas la raison.

Je n'ai trouvé aucun autre ouvrage récent qui atteste ce qu'avançait Julien en 1853, mais il est fort probable que cette étrangeté du française ait ses racines à l'époque de Racine.